# Generate api token for users in database laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have a database of users that work with web login based on laravel sessions. Now I want to generate an api token for each of these users for an api login, how can I generate it? I have already migrated to the database for this new column but I need each user to have their api token.

Comment: The documentation has a [chapter on API authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

Comment: How can I assign the api token to already registered users?

Comment: Write a command that collects every user without an api_token and use `Str::random(80)` as stated in that link to generate one. Save user. Done

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment you to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport). APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests. Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score -1):

If You need session mechanism then You should use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport).

But if You are building traditonal **stateless** REST Api then you can use [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)